# ¿Cómo manejar las preguntas (supuestamentes) duplicadas?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Estoy en duda de una pregunta que se ha cerrado por [duplicado exacto de una pregunta existente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42889/como-alinear-verticalmente-un-div-css). *(La pregunta en sí no es muy buena, lo sé)*

Dice **duplicado exacto** y yo no veo nada que sea exacto, ¿solo porque en la respuesta existente tiene **una** solución que **podría** resolver la duda?

Pero en la pregunta duplicada se le puede dar varias soluciones, una diferente [esta respondida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42890/6491) o también se podría realizar con `cajas flexibles` y hay más soluciones.

Por eso mi duda: si la pregunta en sí no es un duplicado pero otra pregunta con otros contextos tiene una respuesta que les **podría** servir, ¿se cierra como duplicada?

Si es así, manos a la obra... ¡porque hay un montón de preguntas diferentes pero con respuestas similares que podrían marcarse como ***duplicados exacto***!

Comment: Yo creo que deberíamos considerar dos o más preguntas como duplicadas si la respuesta aceptada y/o una respuesta adicional en una pregunta responde directamente a la segunda pregunta. Si no, solo están relacionadas.

Comment: Si sólo estan relacionadas no deberían marcarse como duplicadas. Un link en un comentario es más que suficiente.

Comment: Esto ya me suena más razonable que si son *relacionadas* se deje un comentario... Entonces me viene otra pregunta respecto al usuario *Community*... marque antes esta [pregunta como duplicado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42933/insertar-datos-en-un-array-dentro-de-un-json)... y en unos poco minutos *Community* lo ha cerrado como *duplicado* ... y sstan me ha dejado [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42889/como-alinear-verticalmente-un-div-css?noredirect=1#comment-74144) comentario... pero no creo que el OP acepte que sea un duplicado... o me equivoco? - @MiquelColl

Comment: Es decir... ya no votan los usuarios de la comunidad (con suficiente reputación) si lo consideran como duplicado on no? - @MiquelColl

Comment: Me parece que en ese caso el sistema lo está comparando por título y etiquetas. Antes de votar a reabrir quiero ver si existe alguna pregunta que sea insertar elementos en un array en javascript

Comment: `pregunta duplicada != misma respuesta` ... las personas llegan aquí con una pregunta .. sin saber la respuesta. Que la respuesta sea la misma, no significa que la pregunta sea duplicada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Por eso mi duda: si la pregunta en sí no es un duplicado pero otra pregunta con otros contextos tiene una respuesta que les podría servir, ¿se cierra como duplicada?

## NO

Que la respuesta sea la misma, no significa que la pregunta sea un duplicado. Solo hay que cerrar como duplicado cuando la pregunta trata sobre *el mismo problema técnico*..

La solución esta en otra esfera: Si la solución del problema A tambien soluciona el problema B. Esto no significa cierta otra solución del problema B también solucione el problema A. Por ende, A y B no son iguales y no son el mismo problema.

Esta es la razon, por la que no son duplicados.

Answer (score 3):

Yo creo que deberíamos considerar dos o más preguntas como duplicadas si la respuesta aceptada y/o una respuesta adicional en una pregunta responde directamente a la segunda pregunta (la duplicada). Si no, solo están relacionadas. Hay que tener cuidado que el texto de la pregunta puede ser muy engañoso, por ello es mejor centrarnos en comprender la pregunta. Un ejemplo clásico que he visto en el sitio es con esta pregunta de Java: [Cómo comparar correctamente Strings en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/225/227) la cual tiene muchos duplicados:

- [No entra en la sentencia if, aunque los datos coincidan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6620/227)
- [Ahorro de ArrayList para presentar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/8034/227)
- [Problema con aplicacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/24780/227)

Comment: Ok.. he visto que haz reabierto las dos preguntas *duplicadas*... la pregunta cual voté para cerrar como duplicada era más bien una *prueba* después haber visto que la otra pregunta fue cerrada por duplicado... (no me regañes ahora por eso)... pero quería ver.. si marcamos a una pregunta *relacionada* se cierre así de *fácil*... porque como ya dije se podría cerrar entonces muchas preguntas por duplicado... quizás se debe ajustar un poco el algoritmo del usuario *Community* :)

Comment: @Luiggi: Yo tengo entendido que cuando una pregunta se cierra por `Community`, es que fue porque OP mismo estuvo de acuerdo que la pregunta era un duplicado y la cerró como tal. Referencia: [Why does this question show as “marked as duplicate by Community♦”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287763/why-does-this-question-show-as-marked-as-duplicate-by-community).

Comment: @sstan interesante. No lo sabía. Gracias por la información.